# How to enable loading spinner in power apps, when user open the app?

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas

It takes too long to load data in power apps when the user opens them. Is there any way to load the spinner automatically when the user opens the app, and it should stop when the data is completely loaded in the power app?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the LoadingSpinner property in your Screen component, you can set the value to LoadingSpinner.Data, LoadingSpinner.Controls or LoadingSpinner.None. In your case I think "Data" we'll make it.

In case this doesn't work, you can create a custom spinnng screen.

Here a article that talk about spinners : https://www.spguides.com/power-apps-loading-spinner/

Have a good day